# why gasoline fuel can not ignite on the same diesel engine?

Tags: engine, engine-theory, diesel

I have a diesel engine running. And I switched the diesel fuel to gasoline fuel. It does not ignite at all.  Why ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. if I understood you correctly you mean to say your engine is not turning on.?

Comment: This probably answers your question - https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/19605/why-not-use-gasoline-on-diesel-engines-or-vice-versa

Answer (score 3):

Diesel and petrol/gasoline are totally different fuels, and work in different ways.

Diesel engines are known as 'compression ignition' - Diesel fuel is heavy and has low volatility (meaning that it doesn't burn well), and in a Diesel engine is it injected into a cylinder full of compressed air at a high pressure and temperature, which causes the fuel to ignite.

In a petrol engine on the other hand, the fuel is much thinner, lighter and more volatile, and is ignited by means of a spark - these engines run at much lower pressure.

The two are not compatible, and neither fuel will work in an engine designed for the other.

Answer (score 0):

Diesel is compression ignition  and the gasoline engine is spark ignition..

So you need to provide a spark to ignite the gasoline.

However, in some situations you can get run away of diesel engines where uncontrolled fuel or oil is causing the engine to continue running - these can actually over- rev and fail.